# For loops giving different results on console when run within a function in R

Tags: r, list, function, loops, console

Hokay, so I have a for loop right at the end of this function here that's supposed to output the generated prime numbers that are created early in the function.

When I run the code line by line, everything works as expected and the two for loops output every element in the lists: PrimeList_p, PrimeList_q, to the console window.

When I run the code by calling the function however, the for loops only output the first 20 or so elements to the console. Why doesn't it print the whole list?

```
require(gmp)

GenPrimes <- function(InitialSize) {
#List initialisation
PrimeList_p <<- list()
PrimeList_q <<- list()
#Loop initialisation
x <- 1
#LOOP START
while (x < 81) {
#Generate and compile prime numbers into Prime_List1.
PrimeList_p[[x]] <- nextprime(urand.bigz(size = InitialSize + x, seed = 
Sys.time()))
x <- x+1

PrimeList_q[[x]] <- nextprime(urand.bigz(size = InitialSize + x, seed = 
Sys.time()))
x <- x+1
}

#LOOP END
#Remove NULL entries in lists
PrimeList_p <<- PrimeList_p[-which(sapply(PrimeList_p, is.null))]
PrimeList_q <<- PrimeList_q[-which(sapply(PrimeList_q, is.null))]
cat("Prime p:")
for (i in 1:40){
message(PrimeList_p[[i]])
}
cat("Prime q")
for (j in 1:40){
message(PrimeList_q[[j]])
}
}

GenPrimes(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're incrementing `x` twice in a single loop.  This creates `NULL` entries in both lists which is handled with code, but then saved to the parent environment.  The original lists with `NULL` values still present in the function environment are then passed to the message loops which is why you see a blank line between each value.  Change `for (i in 1:40)` to `for (i in seq_along(PrimeList_p))` and this will become evident